# ESlint cannot override parseOptions

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I cannot make a config to override the main configuration of the eslint.js

**.eslintrc**

```
module.exports = {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
  },
  "globals": {},
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 5,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
    },
  },
 
  "extends": ["myplugin"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
  },
}
```

**eslint-config-myplugin**

```
module.exports = {

      "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6,
      }
   

}
```

i get this error:

0:0  error  Parsing error: sourceType 'module' is not supported when ecmaVersion < 2015. Consider adding `{ ecmaVersion: 2015 }` to the parser options

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s the way it is designed to work, set the parser option to what you need it to be in .eslintrc